# Is there a Set-like object that doesn't store values?

Tags: python, set

I want a data type that will allow me to efficiently keep track of objects that have been "added" to it, allowing me to test for membership. I don't need any other features.

As far as I can tell, Python does not have such a datatype. The closest to what I want is the Set, but the set will always store values (which I do not need).

Currently the best I can come up with is taking the `hash()` of each object and storing it in a set, but at a lower level a hash of the hash is being computed, and the hash string is being stored as a value.

Is there a way to use just the low-level lookup functionality of Sets without actually pointing to anything?

Comment: What happens if you have a hash key collision, and two objects generate the same hash?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of that issue. I suppose it would have to be a trade off of less memory use for a small risk of collisions.

Comment: Whether it is small depends on how good your hash key is.

Comment: My hash key? Why would you use something other than Python's built in `hash()`?

Comment: Didn't mean to imply you should write you own - but just that collisions *will* happen and you have no easy way of knowing how often, so it's very hard to judge the risk! :-)

Comment: Collisions aren't quite as unlikely as you might think, to give you an example, the [enable1](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt) word list, containing just about 170,000 English words (used for Scrabble etc.), already contains 3 collisions, e.g. 'consuming'/'helms'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Set with only existence check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333381/python-set-with-only-existence-check)

Comment: If all you need is to keep track of membership, consider using a bitmap which only stores one bit for each item. You'll have to implement one yourself, but that shouldn't be too hard. You can probably find some clever Python implementations of them if you look around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, no, because, as I pointed out in my comment, it is perfectly possible for two unequal objects to share the same hash key.

The hash key points, not to either nothing or an object, but to a bucket which contains zero or more objects. The set implementation then needs to do equality comparisons against each of these to work out if the object is in the set.

So you always need at least enough information to make an equality comparison. If you've got very large objects whose equality can be decided on a subset of their data, say 2 or 3 fields, you could consider creating a new object with just these fields and storing this in the set instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

`weakref` module implements a bunch of containers that can test membership without "storing" the value, the downside being that when last strong reference to the object is removed, object disappears from a weak container.

If this works for you, `WeakSet` is what you want.

If this doesn't work for you, then it seem you want a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which is probablistic (there are false positives) but for your purpose robust (default is no false negatives).

Typical arrangement is "try in the filter, if no, it's a no; if yes, check the slow way e.g. word list in a file"