# Persistent Hashing of Strings in Python

Tags: python

How would you convert an arbitrary string into a unique integer, which would be the same across Python sessions and platforms? For example `hash('my string')` wouldn't work because a different value is returned for each Python session and platform.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify if you want a guarantee of uniqueness, or if you're satisfied with a high probability of uniqueness, as with a hash function. The fact that you're talking about hash() suggests the latter...? Do you need to be able to invert the mapping, or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a hash function really won't work for you, you can turn the string into a number.

```
my_string = 'my string'
def string_to_int(s):
    ord3 = lambda x : '%.3d' % ord(x)
    return int(''.join(map(ord3, s)))

In[10]: string_to_int(my_string)
Out[11]: 109121032115116114105110103L
```

This is invertible, by mapping each triplet through `chr`.

```
def int_to_string(n)
    s = str(n)
    return ''.join([chr(int(s[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)])

In[12]: int_to_string(109121032115116114105110103L)
Out[13]: 'my string'
```

Comment: This maps '\0' and '\0\0' to the same thing - you should prepend a '1'. Also this is a little inefficient, could use the hex representation so you'd have smaller numbers (this is then equivalent to using the string's binary representation and  interpreting it as a number).

Answer (score 50):

Use a hash algorithm such as MD5 or SHA1, then convert the `hexdigest` via `int()`:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> int(hashlib.md5('Hello, world!').hexdigest(), 16)
144653930895353261282233826065192032313L
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but technically the integer produced is not *unique*. There are less MD5 hashes than available strings. However, chances of a collision are very low

Comment: This is the case for any hash method.

Comment: What does "very low" mean?  Would it be unwise to use this algorithm in production when uniqueness is required?

Comment: If uniqueness is required then don't use a hash; use sequential numbering or a UUID instead.

Comment: Slight modification: If you want to constrain the size of the int:  `int(hashlib.md5('Hello, world!').hexdigest()[:8], 16)` will be < 2**32, `int(hashlib.md5('Hello, world!').hexdigest()[:16], 16)` will be < 2**64.

Comment: in case you want an `int64` (like `hash()`) try: `struct.unpack('l', hashlib.md5('Hello'.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:8])[0]`: it uses all of the first 64 bits, including a sign.

Comment: If you get `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` you need to encode your string, for example: `int(hashlib.md5('Hello, world!'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)`

Answer (score 3):

Here are my python27 implementation for algorithms listed here: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html.
No idea if they are efficient or not.

```
from ctypes import c_ulong

def ulong(i): return c_ulong(i).value  # numpy would be better if available

def djb2(L):
  """
  h = 5381
  for c in L:
    h = ((h << 5) + h) + ord(c) # h * 33 + c
  return h
  """
  return reduce(lambda h,c: ord(c) + ((h << 5) + h), L, 5381)

def djb2_l(L):
  return reduce(lambda h,c: ulong(ord(c) + ((h << 5) + h)), L, 5381)

def sdbm(L):
  """
  h = 0
  for c in L:
    h = ord(c) + (h << 6) + (h << 16) - h
  return h
  """
  return reduce(lambda h,c: ord(c) + (h << 6) + (h << 16) - h, L, 0)

def sdbm_l(L):
  return reduce(lambda h,c: ulong(ord(c) + (h << 6) + (h << 16) - h), L, 0)

def loselose(L):
  """
  h = 0
  for c in L:
    h += ord(c);
    return h
  """
  return sum(ord(c) for c in L)

def loselose_l(L):
  return reduce(lambda h,c: ulong(ord(c) + h), L, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you probably don't *really* want the integers to be actually unique. If you do then your numbers might be unlimited in size. If that really is what you want then you could use a bignum library and interpret the bits of the string as the representation of a (potentially very large) integer. If your strings can include the \0 character then you should prepend a 1, so you can distinguish e.g. "\0\0" from "\0".

Now, if you prefer bounded-size numbers you'll be using some form of hashing. MD5 will work but it's overkill for the stated purpose. I recommend using sdbm instead, it works very well. In C it looks like this:

```
static unsigned long sdbm(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

The source, http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html, also presents a few other hash functions.

Comment: You're quite correct. This would definitely be a problem if I was trying to convert entire documents to a number. However, for my application, I'll only be converting short strings, usually less than a few dozen characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, quite crude (probably has many collisions) and not very legible.

It worked for the purpose of generating an int (and later on, a random color) for different strings:

```
aString = "don't panic"
reduce( lambda x,y:x+y, map( lambda x:ord(x[0])*x[1],zip( aString, range( 1, len( aString ) ) ) ) )
```