# Indexing on nested field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create an index on a nested field, using the Dashboard in AWS Developer Console. E.g. if I have the following schema:

```
{ 'id': 1,
  'nested': {
     'mode': 'mode1',
     'text': 'nice text' 
  }
}
```

I was able to create the index on `nested.mode`, but whenever I then go to query by index, nothing ever comes back. It makes me think that DynamoDB created the index on a field name `nested.mode` instead of the `mode` field of `nested`. Any hints re. what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You cannot (currently) create a secondary index off of a nested attribute. From the [*Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) (emphasis mine):

> For each secondary index, you must specify the following:
>
> ...
>
> - The key schema for the index. **Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Nested attributes and multi-valued sets are not allowed.** Other requirements for the key schema depend on the type of index:

You can, however, [create an index on any top level JSON element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261734/dynamodb-create-index-on-map-or-list-type/30264877#30264877).

Comment: Is this already possible?

Answer (score 0):

[The primary key (partition nor sort key) may not be a nested field.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey)

> Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold
> only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key
> attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such
> restrictions for other, non-key attributes.