# Global Secondary Index Object Property

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to create a global secondary index and project a field from an object?
For example if my documents are in the format:

```
{
  id: 12345,
  account: {
    user: 'john doe'
  },
  ...
}
```

If I create a global secondary index is there a way to use account.user as the key?
Is there a way to have account.user as a projected attribute even if its not the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot key an index on nested document properties. They need to be top-level attributes. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439107/indexing-on-nested-field) for more details.