# DynamoDb querying objects based on nested attribute

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

How can I query all the objects from a given table in Amazon DynamoDb using sub-object id? I will explain with example:

**Orders** table data:

```
{
 "id": "76ds6ds76",
 "publishDate": "2022-09-20",
 "returnDate": null,
 "book": {
  "bookId": "327a7cdfeececd",
  "name": "Hello world"
 }
},
{
 "id": "838ds990",
 "publishDate": "2022-09-30",
 "returnDate": null,
 "book": {
  "bookId": "327a7cdfeececd",
  "name": "Hello world"
 }
}
```

I want to get all the **Orders** with *bookId == "327a7cdfeececd"*. Is there any possibility to query that?

Comment: Not really. That is not what DynamoDB is designed for. You cannot put indices onto nested attributes. Move `bookId` and `name` up into the top level and you can put an index onto it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441854/2442804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can achieve that is by making `bookid` a top level attribute and creating a GSI based on it.

The other option you have is using a Scan and FilterExpression. This will read all the items in the table in order to find the one you need, while it would work well for small tables, it may not be advisable to do it with large tables due to poor performance and cost.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression

Comment: Thank you Lee, I'll have to think about some refactor then.