# How to create Global Secondary Index for Json Attributes(column values) in Amazon Dynamo DB in C#?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with column Id and JSON column.

```
Id       |       JSON
----------------------------------------------------------------
101      |  {"person_id":456,"f_name":"t", "l_name":"Jack"}
         |
102      |  {"person_id":123,"f_name":"M", "l_name":"Ron"}
         |
103      |  {"person_id":789,"f_name":"A", "l_name":"Tom"}
```

I am able to create GSI(Global Secondary Index) on column Id , but I would like to know how to create GSI on `person_id` and `f_name`. Is it possible to create GSI for json attributes? As upon observation, I was able to create GSI on columns in tables of Dynamo DB. Please provide a C#.Net example.

[image: DynamoDB].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DynamoDB create index on map or list type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261734/dynamodb-create-index-on-map-or-list-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

> Q: Is querying JSON data in DynamoDB any different?
>
> No. You can create a Global Secondary Index or Local Secondary Index
>   on any top-level JSON element. For example, suppose you stored a JSON
>   document that contained the following information about a person:
>   First Name, Last Name, Zip Code, and a list of all of their friends.
>   First Name, Last Name and Zip code would be top-level JSON elements.
>   You could create an index to let you query based on First Name, Last
>   Name, or Zip Code. The list of friends is not a top-level element,
>   therefore you cannot index the list of friends. For more information
>   on Global Secondary Indexing and its query capabilities, see the
>   Secondary Indexes section in this FAQ.
>
> Q: If I have nested JSON data in DynamoDB, can I retrieve only a
>   specific element of that data?
>
> Yes. When using the GetItem, BatchGetItem, Query, or Scan APIs, you
>   can define a ProjectionExpression to determine which attributes should
>   be retrieved from the table. Those attributes can include scalars,
>   sets, or elements of a JSON document.

Although I haven't managed to do it, or seen any examples of it being done with cloud formation.

Comment: Can you please provide a small example on how to create GSI on Json top level elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a GSI or LSI on any top-level JSON element. So you have to bring the json element to column level and then create the index.

Comment: Yes even I think the same. I am able to create Index for columns in top-level of JSON..