# Dynamodb index with Json attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am referring to a thread [creating an index with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287356/how-to-create-global-secondary-index-for-json-attributescolumn-values-in-amazo)

I have a column called **data** in my DynamoDB table. This is in JSON and the structure of this file looks like this:

```
{
"config": "aasdfds",
"state":"PROCESSED",
"value" "asfdasasdf"
}
```

The AWS documentation says that I can create an index with the top level JSON attribute. However I don't know how to do this exactly. When I create the index, should I specify the partition key as **data.state**, then, in my code, use a query with the column **data.state** with the value set to **PROCESSED**, or should I create the partition key as **data**, then, in my code, look for the column **data** with the value set to **state = "PROCESSED"** ?

Answer (score 4):

Top level attribute means DynamoDB supports creating index on Scalar attributes only (String, Number, or Binary).

The JSON attribute is stored as Document data type. So, index can't be created on Document data type.

> The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema
>   must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Other
>   data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed.
>
> Scalar Types – A scalar type can represent exactly one value. The
>   scalar types are number, string, binary, Boolean, and null.
>
> Document Types – A document type can represent a complex structure
>   with nested attributes—such as you would find in a JSON document. The
>   document types are list and map.
>
> Set Types – A set type can represent multiple scalar values. The set
>   types are string set, number set, and binary set.