# DynamoDBMapper - DynamoDBDocument and local secondary indexes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using DynamoDB SDK 1.11.185 version. I have a Client entity mapped to Clients DynamoDB table through DynamoDBMapper annotations. One of the attributes contains nested values (see code examples below). I want to add a local secondary index to zone attribute from Options class. Once I want to save an object, I got a null pointer exception from this class

*com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel*

line 415. Looks like a bug from the libraries.

P.D. If I generate the index over clientId attribute from Client entity, everything work fine.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Clients")
public class Client {

    private String id;
    private String clientId;
    private Date created;
    private Options options;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(String id, String clientId, Options options) {
        this.id = id;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.options = options;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getClientId() { return clientId; }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) { this.clientId = clientId; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public Options getOptions() { return options; }
    public void setOptions(Options options) { this.options = options; }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public Date getCreated() { return created; }
    public void setCreated(Date created) { this.created = created; }
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class Options {

    private String zone;

    public Options() {
    }

    public Options(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(localSecondaryIndexName = "zone-index")
    public String getZone() { return zone; }
    public void setZone(String zone) { this.zone = zone; }

}
```

**************************** EDITED *************************

Correct answer by @Raniz and
[Indexing on nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439107/indexing-on-nested-field)

It can be done using JSON attributes though:
[DynamoDB create index on map or list type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261734/dynamodb-create-index-on-map-or-list-type/30264877#30264877)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use nested attributes in the key schema for an index.

I assume you've created the index with *options.zone* in the schema which means that DynamoDB is expecting a top-level attribute with that exact name - i.e. an attribute named *options.zone* and not an attribute named *zone* nested under the *options* attribute.

Excerpt from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html):

> - The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema
>     must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Other
>     data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed. Other requirements for the key schema depend on the type of index:
>
>   - For a global secondary index, the partition key can be any scalar attribute of the base table. A sort key is optional, and it too can be
>       any scalar attribute of the base table.
>   - For a local secondary index, the partition key must be the same as the base table's partition key, and the sort key must be a non-key
>       base table attribute.

To use *zone* in your index schema you'll need to either move or duplicate it so it's available on the top level. The easiest way of accomplishing this would probably be to add a getter to `Client` that returns `options.zone`:

```
@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(localSecondaryIndexName = "zone-index")
public String getZone() {
    if (options != null) {
        return options.getZone();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Raniz for answering. Actually I just found out my question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439107/indexing-on-nested-field. I will try to use the approach you propoused and come back to you. Marking it as correct though.