# Python convert an integer to fixed or varying size recoverable string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get a string from an integer as:

`convert(45)
 VHCDD65D2D5SS`

This string should also be able to give back the integer. 
What should be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: What's the relationship of `'VHCDD65D2D5SS'` to `45`, exactly?

Comment: A dictionary? `{"45": "VHCDD65D2D5SS"}`

Comment: you can also just convert 45 to string, i.e 45-->"45"

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy There is no relation between these two. I want to get a random string (token) generated using an integer (id).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a hash method. [Hashlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008760/9816541) or with [Salt and hash a password in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python)

To generate the token, I think you can add extra char in front of the ID

Example:
ID = 1 
string_id = name_1 
hashlib = xxxxxx